# How to use jq to select from value array

Tags: json, jq

I have data like this:

```
$ cat foo.json
{"s1": [{"answer": 1, "count": 90}, {"answer": 0, "count": 10}]}
{"s2": [{"answer": 1, "count": 85}, {"answer": 0, "count": 15}]}
```

I'm trying to use `jq` to extract the count of the `1` answer for each key, with this desired result:

```
{"s1": 90, "s2": 85}
```

Update -- this result would be equally useful:

```
{"s1": 90}
{"s2": 85}
```

How can I do that with `jq`?

Answer (score 1):

This gives the originally requested result:

```
jq -s '[ .[]
         | .[] = (.[][])
         | select(.[].answer == 1)
         | .[] = .[].count
       ] | add' foo.json
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this solution works:

```
jq -c 'with_entries(.value = (.value[] | select(.answer==1) | .count))' foo.json
{"s1":90}
{"s2":85}
```

There may be a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: That doesn't look like your desired result, though, no?

Comment: Good point, but that's fine as well, I only care about extracting these counts. I'll update the question.